# Coloring Tables in Vaadin

Tags: java, css, vaadin

I have 3 table components attached to some layout in my Vaadin application. I want to have different background color for all of my 3 tables. I mean to say that table1 has blue color, table2 has yellow color and table3 has red color. How can I achieve such thing in vaadin.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it in the following way:

Add following CSS to your styles.css file

```
.classname .v-table-body{
yourstyle goes here
}
```

set the style of the table as follows:

table1.setStyleName("classname");

it will apply the style for table1 only

Comment: You should do the same thing for the two other tables as well. But yes, by assigning style names for components allows you to define component instance specific themes.

Comment: I suspect you want [`addStyleName`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Component.html#addStyleName(java.lang.String)) rather than [`setStyleName`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Component.html#setStyleName%28java.lang.String%29). The `setStyleName` method removes other applied CSS.